# c++ Roman Additive Form Conversion

Tags: c++, string, roman-numerals

I'm working in a program that converts from Roman to Decimal. I have to validate 2 things: One that the characters entered are M or D or C or L or X or V or I, in other words valid for processing.

Number two, I have to make sure that bigger characters value go first and if not to print and error message and have the user to try again (this is the part where I am stuck)

For instance, If I wanted to input 9 and I input IX it should display an error message because is not in [Additive form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148615/roman-numerals-subtractive-vs-additive). It should be VIIII. How can I code this so it compares characters to know whether bigger letter values are first and so on?

I keep getting incorrect validation.
Is there a way to assign a value to the letters in the string? I'm thinking in comparing them as int values which I know how to and from there validate input format.

```
void RomanNum::setRomanNumber() //get input and calculate decimal equivalent
{
    //I 1, V 5, X 10, L 50, C 100, D 500, M 1000
    int value = 0;
    string input;
    char current, next;
    enum validationData { M, D, C, L, X, V, I };
    bool validationCharacters = true;
    //bool validationAdditiveForm = true;

    getline(cin, input, '\n');

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) //calculate each Roman letter at a time
    {
        current = input[i];
        next = current + 1;
        if (current >= validationData(next))
        {
            switch (input[i])
            {
                case 'M':
                    value += 1000;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    value += 500;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    value += 100;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    value += 50;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                    value += 10;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    value += 5;
                    break;
                case 'I':
                    value += 1;
                    break;
                default:
                    validationCharacters = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid order. Bigger values go first\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that IX or IV are valid roman numerals. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but my teacher wants it to be in descendant order. Thats the thing in here @Docteur Docteur

Comment: Exactly as Docteur said: "Good luck". You need to try to come up with a solution on your own. If you have a problem with one of your ideas, come here and ask. if you want to know which one is the most elegant, ask on the codereview sister site.

Comment: Its been 2 hours trying so far with no luck... I try to validate it with a second for loop before the switch but I keep getting errors. Should I upload that version? @stefan

Comment: One way is to translate the characters to something with the desired order, e.g. `enum RomanDigit { I, V, X, L, C, D, M };`). Then you can just test if `the last digit read >= this digit`. You will also most likely get into less trouble if you follow the order 1) read the input, 2) validate the input, 3) perform the actual calculations, 4) output the results.

Comment: An enum isn't going to be convenient. It contains C++ symbols and numerical values. He needs to match a character.

Comment: @MSalters Yes, I update my code with enum stuff and I am getting incorrect validation.

Comment: Is the exercise merely to validate correct order? e.g. You should consider IX to be invalid, and the correct notation for nine to be VIIII?

Comment: @dgel thats right. That is how I have to do it. IX would be invalid, it should it be XI to be valid.

Comment: @AdrianPxndx, XI is 11, IX is 9. Do you mean the number nine should be impossible to form? Should you validate this?

Comment: @dgel If the user wanted to input 9. It should be inputed as VIIII. The biggest at the beginning, and completing the number with smaller values. Like giving change

Comment: @AdrianPxndx, in that case, MSalters' answer is correct, you should mark it as accepted answer, it's a simple and correct solution

Comment: @dgel: I've linked a MathOverflow issue on Roman Numerals Additive Form. VIIII is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a `std::map<char, int>` to hold the mapping between letetrs and values.

With the map, you can then convert the input string (a sequence of characters) to a sequence of values (`std::vector<int>`). From there on, it's just a single check to see if the vector is sorted, and a single function call to add up all values. (I'll leave finding the right function as homework)

Comment: I kind of did it in another inefficient and long way, because I haven't learn how to use maps yet. Thanks for the tip thought.

Comment: You can indeed write `if (character=='D') vec.push_back(1000); else if (character == 'C' ... ` instead.